# How to animate a number ticking up in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a number "tick up" when it changes, in a similar fashion to Twitter's like/retweet/comment counters and Discord's reaction counter. I haven't found any information about this on the web (mainly because I don't know what it's formally called).

[image]

Here is my code:

The counter element itself:

```html
<span id="counter" class="counter">0</span>
```

The CSS for the element:

```css
.counter {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

The JavaScript for changing the counter:

```js
function changeCounter(id, num) {
    var _x = document.getElementById(id);
    _x.innerHTML += _x.innerHTML + "<br>" + num;
    _x.style.transition = "0.2s";
    setTimeout(function () {
        _x.style.marginTop = "-15px";
        setTimeout(function () {
            _x.innerHTML = num;
            _x.style.transition = "0";
            _x.style.marginTop = "0";
        }, 200);
    }, 16);
}
```

What happens is that it puts the new number next to the original number, goes up, and goes down with just the new number. I want it to have the new number under the old one and just snap to its original position after it stops animating.

```js
function changeCounter(id, num) {
    var _x = document.getElementById(id);
    _x.innerHTML += _x.innerHTML + "<br>" + num;
    _x.style.transition = "0.2s";
    setTimeout(function () {
        _x.style.marginTop = "-15px";
        setTimeout(function () {
            _x.innerHTML = num;
            _x.style.transition = "0";
            _x.style.marginTop = "0";
        }, 200);
    }, 16);
}
```

```css
.counter {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span id="counter" class="counter">0</span>

<button onclick="changeCounter('counter', Math.floor(Math.random()*100))">Change</button>
```

Comment: Whoops, looks like I forgot to paste the code

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @PeterThoeny updated to add the code, sorry about that

Comment: Why was this closed??? Jeez, you can't ask anything on SO anymore...